# Implement AJAX for header navigation

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a WordPress site and here is header navigation that comes using this WordPress function:

```
wp_nav_menu();
```

I want to implement AJAX for this menu, meaning only the content area should be changed rather then to reloading a complete page.

I am not getting how to do this in WordPress.
Please provide me your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use your own ajax files and load it in header to use in menus or other places please point to this question , i answered this later.

[WordPress navigation with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464419/wordpress-navigation-with-images/8464445#8464445)

Comment: thanks for reply actually prob is not that how to use ajex in wp I need how to show content for particular page when user click on menu should be through ajex. Mean when user click on contact page then conatct form should be display through ajex

Comment: shalu i read this page carefully and my webpage is fully working with ajax:

`http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins`